# Showing loading animation until content loaded

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have been using Nuxtjs for a while in many of my projects, but I can't seem to figure how to achieve this. I want to prevent the user from viewing a content web they load my website until everything is ready, like what happens in the [Google Adsense website](https://ads.google.com) https://ads.google.com. I want to display an animation until everything is loaded before removing the animation

Comment: What have you tried? If nothing, I would start by adjusting the Nuxt.js custom loading example (https://nuxtjs.org/examples/custom-loading) for use with pages/_app.js or pages/_document.js and updating this post with your source.

Comment: Okay @SteveHynding i will try that.

Comment: Just wrap whatever you want to hide "until it's ready" in a `v-if="isLoading"` and have another element following it `<div class="loader" v-else>` containing the loading animation of your choice. At which point all you need to do is set `isLoading` to `true` or `false` at the appropriate times.